# Prove the function $Q: \Bbb R^3\to C[0,1],\;\langle a,b,c\rangle \mapsto ax^2+bx+c$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

The following map $Q : \Bbb R^3 \to C[0, 1]$: if $(a, b, c)$ is any point in $\Bbb R^3$, then $Q(a, b,c) = f$ is the quadratic polynomial in $C[0, 1]$ given by the formula：

$$Q(a, b, c)(x) = f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$

for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$.

Assume that $\Bbb R^3$ has the Euclidean metric and $C[0,1]$ has the metric

$$d(f,g) = \sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}$$

Prove that $Q$ is continuous.

Comment: Why do you think $Q$ is Liptchitz?

Comment: I think the simplest way is prove continuity of each monomial term, then infer continuity of the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $(a_n,b_n,c_n)\rightarrow (a,b,c)$ which is equivalent to $a_n\rightarrow a$, $b_n\rightarrow b$, and $c_n\rightarrow c$

Then

$d(Q(a_n,b_n,c_n),Q(a,b,c))=\sup\{|(a_n-a)x^2+(b_n-b)x+(c_n-c)|\}$

$\le\sup\{|a_n-a|\cdot|x^2|+|b_n-b|\cdot|x|+|c_n-c)|\}$

$\le\sup\{|a_n-a|+|b_n-b|+|c_n-c)|\}\rightarrow 0$

as $|x|\le 1$ and $|x^2|\le 1$

So $Q$ is continuous.

Comment: does that also mean $(f_n)$ converges to $Q$

Comment: yes, this is what we proved. $(a_n, b_n, c_n)\rightarrow (a,b,c)\Rightarrow Q(a_n, b_n, c_n)\rightarrow Q(a,b,c)$ The first convergence is in the Euclidean (or any other metric since they are all equivalent), and the second convergence is in the $\sup$ metric on the space of the continuous functions.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate? $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ converges to $(a,b,c)$ so one might assume that $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$  is in a closed ball about $(a,b,c)$  for $n$ large enough; not about $(0,0,0)$ as you say.

Comment: for all $n ∈ N$, $(a_n, b_n, c_n) ∈ B$, where B is the closed ball in $R^3$ about $(0, 0, 0)$ of radius 10: $B = \{ (a, b, c) \in R^3 :\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} \leq 10  \}$. $(f_n)$ converges to $Q$

Comment: It seems to me that what you said would only prove that $Q$ is continuous at $(0,0,0)$ or inside $B$. But why would you want to bound the sequence by a sphere of radius $10$? What I am using is simply this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences) of continuity.

Comment: my question  says $R^3$ has the Euclidean metric but not the standard metric

Comment: AFAIK, the standard metric is the Euclidean metric. If your metric is given by a norm, then all norm metrics are equivalent on $\mathbb R^n$, so the proof holds without modifications. But if you are using some other strange norm, I don't know whether it holds or not. Can you tell us the definition of the norm that you are using in order to further help you?

Comment: I mean "some strange metric" not norm.

Comment: Can you correct it so it makes sense mathematically?

Comment: The Euclidean metric in $R^n$ is defined as $d(x,z) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n = (x_i-z_i)}$ . n is the dimension of R.

Comment: What I don't understand is the meaning of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}=(x_i-z_i)$. What's the meaning of this?

Comment: for this question, it means distance between the two points $(a,b,c)$ and $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$ is $\sqrt{(a-a_0)^2 +(b-b_0)^2 +(c-c_0)^2    }$.  sry I miseed the square in the formular.

Comment: So it is the standard Euclidean distance. Then everything is fine with the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_0,b_0,c_0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\vert (a,b,c) - (a_0,b_0,c_0) \vert < \epsilon/3$ and note that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \sup_{x \in [0,1]}\vert (a - a_0)x^2 + (b - b_0)x + c - c_0\vert \\
&\leq \sup_{x \in [0,1]}\vert a - a_0\vert x^2 + \sup_{x \in [0,1]}\vert b - b_0 \vert x + \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \vert c - c_0 \vert \\
&= \vert a - a_0 \vert + \vert b - b_0 \vert + \vert c - c_0 \vert.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in [0,1]$ we have $\vert (Q(a, b, c)-Q(a_0,b_0,c_0))(x)\vert$  =

$\vert (a-a_0)x^2 + (b-b_0)x+(c-c_0)\vert\le \vert a-a_0\vert +\vert b-b_0\vert+\vert c-c_0\vert$.

Since this is true for all $x\in [0,1]$ it follows that

$\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\vert Q(a,b,c)(x)-Q(a_0,b_0,c_0)(x)\vert \le \vert a-a_0\vert +\vert b-b_0\vert+\vert c-c_0\vert$.

Now let $a\to a_0;\ b\to b_0$ and $c\to c_0$

Comment: my question says $R^3$ has the Euclidean metric but no the standard metric